# How can i force cursor to stay in place on window when dragging an Undecorated Stage

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to create  gui calculator with an undecorated stage. I added an Hbox as the title bar and set gave it an onClicked/OnDragged methods to move the primary stage around when dragged, however it doesn't seem to work perfectly. because

1) When i press and start dragging, the mouse cursor moves to the top left corner of the window as you can see below. The method i used is from here

**X** IMAGES:

[When i click on middle of Hbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iED8c.png)

[Where the cursor moves when i start dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddd0e.png)

**X** Here is my main class

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));


    Scene mainSCENE = new Scene(root);
    mainSCENE.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("calculator.css").toExternalForm());
    mainSCENE.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(mainSCENE);


    mainWindow = primaryStage;

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

**X** and here are the methods i used in my Controller class to add the draggable effect

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
Circle btnCLOSE;

@FXML
Circle btnMINIMIZE;

@FXML
HBox hboxTitleBar;
private double xOffset = 0;
private double yOffset = 0;


public void handle(MouseEvent event) throws IOException, LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {

    // Plays click audio when buttons are clicked
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("click.wav"));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioIn);
    clip.start();

    // Add functionality to minimize/close buttons
    btnCLOSE.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event1 -> System.exit(0));
    btnMINIMIZE.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event1 -> Main.mainWindow.setIconified(true));
}


// Makes the UNDECORATED window draggable from the title bar Hbox
public void setOnClicked(MouseEvent event) {

    System.out.println("CLICKED");
    xOffset = Main.mainWindow.getX() - event.getScreenX();
    yOffset = Main.mainWindow.getY() - event.getScreenY();
}

public void setOnDragged(MouseEvent event) {

    Main.mainWindow.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);
    Main.mainWindow.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);
}
}
```

How can i **lock the cursor in place** when dragging?

2) When i click the close/minimize buttons that are inside the HBox, it also drags the window. Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To facilitate the movement of your entire window you need two events, (Press/ Drag), the action starts when you press the bar, by initializing the position of (`xOffset, yOffset`), I think **if i'm not mistaken** the error you have made Is that you used the screen rather than the scene Here is the solution to your first problem :

```
//Use Press Event instead of Click Event
xOffset = event.getSceneX();
yOffset = event.getSceneY();

//Drag Event
window.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
window.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
```

for the second problem, you can add your close button outside the layout this is **for me** the simplest solution.