# JavaFX dragging Pane around

Tags: java, javafx, drag, pane

I am trying to enable dragging of a pane in my java fx application using this code:

```
setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            setManaged(false);
            this.setTranslateX(event.getX()-120);
            this.setTranslateY(event.getY()-50);
            event.consume();

        });
```

But when I try to drag it, it drags but also appears in another place every few frames, so it looks like it is in two places, when I let go of the pane, it ends up in one of these places.
Does anyone know why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i force cursor to stay in place on window when dragging an Undecorated Stage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953875/how-can-i-force-cursor-to-stay-in-place-on-window-when-dragging-an-undecorated-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates provided by `MouseEvent` are provided in local coordinates. If the you modify the `translate` properties the position of the object is modified and the origin local coordinate system is moved too.

This means decreasing a translate property will increase the corresponding mouse coordinate by the same value. Increasing the translate property will decrease the corresponding mouse coordinate in the next event. This makes the node jump around.

Possible solutions are using coordinates in the parent or another coordinate not influenced by the translate property or by taking the current translate property into account:

```
setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
    setManaged(false);
    this.setTranslateX(event.getX() + this.getTranslateX() - 120);
    this.setTranslateY(event.getY() + this.getTranslateY() - 50);
    event.consume();
});
```

Note that hardcoding the offsets makes the node jump in the first event, but not in consequtive events.

Comment: I know about the offset,  I was just testing it out, I decided to use event.getSceneX() to get the value, this way it isn't relative.

Answer (score -2):

I think this question has already an answer here [Drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953875/how-can-i-force-cursor-to-stay-in-place-on-window-when-dragging-an-undecorated-s/40960481#40960481), but to perform that, you need two events (`Press` `Drag`) the first one to tell the window from where the drag has begun and the second to perform the drag itself.